# Issues with Add-ins Created for Outlook

Tags: azure, outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins

Deployed version of Outlook Add-in works fine with the domain account. But unable to use the Add-in with different domain account.

Example: hosted in ABC.com able to add the outlook Add-in with the same domain account. But when tried adding that with different domain example.com it failed.

Outlook mobile Add-In created with someexample.com domain throws exception while used in the outlook Mobile app. The same works fine with desktop version

MobileFormFactor is updated & verified using the below link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-mobile-support

```
      <MobileFormFactor>
        <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
        <!-- Message read form -->
        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
          <Group id="mobileMsgRead">
            <Label resid="readGrpLabel" />
          <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="ctrlMsgRdAssign">
            <Label resid="rdCtrlLbl" />
              <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="icn-assign-case-25" />
                <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="icn-assign-case-25" />
                <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="icn-assign-case-25" />

                <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="icn-assign-case-32" />
                <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="icn-assign-case-32" />
                <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="icn-assign-case-32" />

                <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="icn-assign-case-48" />
                <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="icn-assign-case-48" />
                <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="icn-assign-case-48" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <SourceLocation resid="urlAssign"/>
              </Action>
            </Control>
          </Group>
        </ExtensionPoint>

      </MobileFormFactor>
```

Error While Accessing Mobile Add-In
authTokenResError error: undefined{}

Comment: When you say "domain" are you referring to the location of the web server hosting the add-in, or the mailbox where you've installed the add-in?

Comment: Refers to the location on the web server.

Comment: Are you getting the error when adding the add-in, or when loading the add-in?

Comment: Satheesh, are you adding / removing / re-adding the manifest with the same app id, but different target URLs?  I had a similar issue before a couple times, and if your client is still logged in, it remembers the token based on the "audience" which is your URL where your app is being served from.  If you change it, but it appears to be the same app, your client is still using a token but the audience changed, so token is invalid.  You can try changing the guid corresponding to app in the manifest and remove/re-add it.